# Escrevi um texto para estudar a nova ortografia, está correto?

Tags: acordo-ortográfico

Estou **estudando para concurso** e escrevi um texto meio doido (assim é bom para decorar) para lembrar a nova ortografia. Usei palavras com **as mudanças mais significativas**  baseadas neste artigo: [Novo Acordo Ortográfico passa a valer em 2016; veja o que muda](https://www.acheconcursos.com.br/artigo/dicas-de-lingua-portuguesa-para-concursos-e-o-novo-acordo-ortografico)

Pelo que vi está certo, estou postando aqui para me certificar:

> No **dia a dia** eu venho utilizando um **pé de cabra**, mas dá uma
>   **mão de obra...** Então chamei meu **coirmão**, aliás **não fumante**, que já foi **cofundador** da Microsoft, que chegou a fazer uma **coprodução** com a Apple, agora sua **arqui-inimiga**, antes no **semi-hemisfério**,
>   agora no mundo todo. Isso mostra um **autorretrato** global, uma
>   verdadeira **contrarrevolução**...
>
> Mas tive uma **ideia** e fui na **assembleia**. De forma **heroica**
>   parecia um **paranoico** que deu ate **enjoo**.
>
> Por falar em **enjoo** lembrei do **voo** que estudei acordo
>   **linguístico**, bah.

Comment: Obrigado Jorge B

Comment: De nada. Seja bem-vindo ao site. Só uma coisa, o título estava melhor como estava, aqui as perguntas têm de ser claras e objetivas. Ao perguntar "Está certo?" ou "Está correto" alguém vai responder que sim ou que não e dizer o porquê objetivamente, mas ao você pedir sugestões já deixa a pergunta meia ambígua.

Comment: Aconselho a fazer o nosso [tour] e a ver [ask].

Comment: Para mim esta pergunta está off-topic. Antes de fazer uma pergunta sobre a grafia correta, deves consultar um dicionário; e fazer a pergunta só se o dicionário não te deixar esclarecido, explicando porque é que não ficaste esclarecido. Há vários dicionários online: [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/dia%20a%20dia); a [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/p%C3%A9%20de%20cabra) (baseado em Portugal) que, para as palavras que mudaram, indica a grafia nova e a antiga.

Comment: [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/coirm%C3%A3o), que indica diferenças nas grafias do Brasil e Portugal, mas parece não ter atualizado algumas palavras com hífens. Além da pesquisa prévia, a pergunta deve ser específica: não um texto para rever, mas sim uma pergunta por cada palavra em que te subsistam dúvidas depois da consulta dos dicionários (na minha experiência vale a pena consultar mais do que um).

Comment: Voto para fechar a pergunta pelas razões expostas acima.

Comment: OK boas dicas, desculpem algo, somente queria uma segunda opinião